# UPDATE row relative to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not giving the correct value

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, dateadd

I am trying to update a MySQL table with an 'expiration date'. I've collected a timestamp value for all my rows as people have registered into the table but now I want to create an expiration date relative to that timestamp (not to relative to the current time). Here's my code:

```
$timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
$sql_update = "
UPDATE jobs
SET expiration_date = DATE_ADD('$timestamp',INTERVAL 56 DAY)";
$result_update = $mysqli->query($sql_update) or die($mysqli->error);
```

Understand that this is being run in a 'while' loop so it's running through each row of the table an updating them as it goes. The issue is that I ran it once and all it did was update the 'expiration_date' row to 56 days from NOW not 56 days from the timestamp's value. The timestamp is set on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for when the a new entry is registered which I'm assuming is the problem. I've echoed out $timestamp to troubleshoot and it echoes out the correct value (not the current time) when I echo it but when it goes to actually update the expiration date it seems to be drawing from the fact that it's a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Is there a way to explicit query for the value of the timestamp?

I'm hoping to find a way that doesn't involved restructuring the database. I know I could have it so instead of a timestamp row, I could make it a datetime row and set it to the value of NOW() when database is being initially queried to add a row but I'd prefer to find a solution within the way the table is currently set up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably somehow the value in `$timestamp` is wrong.

Try adding the timestamp directly in the query using the column name. E.g. : `DATE_ADD(timestamp,INTERVAL 56 DAY)`

What you are currently doing, hardly makes any sense. You first get the timestamp from the database and assign it to the `$timestamp` variable, only to use it in the query again..
In situations like these, you can better directly use the column name to access the data in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why are you running this query in loop ?
You can use only one sql statement. Update from select;

```
update jobs a set a.expiration_date = DATE_ADD(a.timestampFieldName,INTERVAL 56 DAY), a.timestampFieldName = a.timestampFieldName;
```

I supose that there is some "bug" (don't know) in MySQL because if you don't add `a.timestampFieldName = a.timestampFieldName` then this field will be set to current timestamp;